# Calling a function in same scope in another function -AngularJS - Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I have this code and I have made a refresh function which states the purpose obviously. I have to refresh other stats as well but I can't call it inside the "refresh" function below even they are in **same** scope. I am sure that I am calling it right but console keeps giving the following **error:**

***ReferenceError: getAllCustomers is not defined***

```
  $scope.getAllCustomers = new function(){
        $http.post('
          <?php echo site_url('angularjs/get_users_by_type/'); ?>',
                          {userType:'C'}).then(function(response) {

         $scope.totalCustomer = response.data.count;

      }, function(response) {
          console.log(response);
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
      });
    };

   // getAllCustomer etc all defined before this function but the following errors keeps coming on the console that getAllCustomers is not a function. 
        $scope.refresh = new function(){
            getAllCustomers();

        };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `new` keyword while declaring function, It should be

```
$scope.getAllCustomers = function()
```

Answer (score 1):

check your code like this:

```
   $scope.getAllCustomers = function(){
        $http.post('
          <?php echo site_url('angularjs/get_users_by_type/'); ?>',
                          {userType:'C'}).then(function(response) {

         $scope.totalCustomer = response.data.count;

      }, function(response) {
          console.log(response);

      });
    };


        $scope.refresh = function(){
            $scope.getAllCustomers();

        };
```